# What is an efficient way to store and retrieve an arbitrary depth nested structure in postgres?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, hierarchical-data

In my ruby-on-rails app, I have nested comments that can be nested an arbitrary length.

I tried different ways of storing this:

Using self joins:

```
belongs_to :parent, :class_name => 'Comment', :foreign_key => 'parent_id'
has_many :children, :class_name => 'Comment', :foreign_key => "parent_id"
```

Using ancestry gem

etc

The problem, though, is that no matter what I use, there will always be an linear number of SQL statements. (1 statement to grab all the root comments, and then 1 statement for each root's children, and then 1 statement for all the children of that, etc)

Is there a more efficient way to accomplish this?

Postgres 9.1, but hopefully backwards compatible solutions are preferred.

Comment: There's a vast difference between "arbitrary" and "infinite" :-)

Comment: Point noted. Though isn't it rather pedantic? Clearly, there is no possible way to store an infinitely nested structure :P

Comment: Pedantry is my speciality. Well, that and anal retentiveness :-)

Comment: postgres 9.1, but backwards compatible solutions are great too

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the most efficient/elegant way to parse a flat table into a tree?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/192220/what-is-the-most-efficient-elegant-way-to-parse-a-flat-table-into-a-tree)

Comment: @RazorStorm could you define what you mean by "efficient" (space or speed)?  It would also help to know how much data is stored in each of the nodes.  Representing and walking the graph separately from the leaf node data might be your best bet if it's large and frequently traversed.

Comment: I am hoping for speed efficiency. At the moment, I am grabbing the first layer of comments from db, then grabbing their children, then their children, etc. As I do this, I put this data into a tree.

On the view, I do a preorder traversal of the tree to render each comment.

Comment: Any reason for not using an existing plugin/gem (e.g. [ancestry](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry))?

Comment: I tried with ancestry, (as I stated above), but it tends to create a huge amount of sql statements. I was wondering if it is possible to make this more efficient speedwise

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could stick with your `parent_id` pointer column and use [`find_by_sql`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#method-c-find_by_sql) and a [`WITH RECURSIVE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html) query and let the database do all the work in one shot. Something like this:

```
comments = Comment.find_by_sql(%Q{
    with recursive tree(id) as (
        select c.id, c.column1, ...
        from comments c
        where c.id in (#{roots.join(',')})
        union all
        select c.id, c.column1, ...
        from comments c
        join tree on c.parent_id = tree.id
    )
    select id, column1, ...
    from tree
})
```

where `roots` would be a Ruby array holding the `id`s of the root nodes that you're interested in. That will give you all the nodes in the subtrees of interest as Comment instances. I've used queries like this in the past and WITH RECURSIVE was well over twice as fast as your iterative technique even with shallow trees, I'd guess that deeper trees would see even better speed ups.

The `parent_id` structure you're using is very convenient for most things and meshes quite well with how ActiveRecord wants to work. Also, sticking with your current structure means that you can leave the rest of your application alone.

WITH RECURSIVE is available in PostgreSQL 8.4 and higher.

Comment: Doing this seems to present me with a flat list. Do I have to recreate the tree structure (for rendering) algorithmically or is there a shortcut?

Comment: @Razor: That will pull out the tree out of the database in one go, then you have to put it back together in Ruby. If your goal is just to render the tree then a materialized path approach (using PostgreSQL arrays for the paths) would work.

Comment: @muistooshort postgreSQL now has separate datatype to support materialised path named ltree and this is one of the gem which uses it and gives helper functions https://github.com/cfabianski/ltree_hierarchy

Answer (score 1):

Take a look a awesome_nested_set, I think you will like it.

https://github.com/collectiveidea/awesome_nested_set

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of articles that discuss the classical (i.e. basic SQL based) options.  For instance, [this](https://evilmartians.com/chronicles/postgresql-and-rails-sitting-in-a-tree) is a decent summary of the classical options and this [article](https://hashrocket.com/blog/posts/recursive-sql-in-activerecord) covers using recursive queries with rails.

However, since you are using Postgressql (and if not start) you have the option of using the [ltree extension](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/postgresql-speeding-up-recursive-queries-and-hierarchic-data/) which creates indexes specifically suited for tree structures.  I would have used [ltree_hierarchy](https://github.com/cfabianski/ltree_hierarchy) but it turns out that postgres doesn't support dashes in the ltree labels making this incompatible with using uuids for my ids.  I settled on the [ancestry gem](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry) despite it not using the nice features (only other real choice in 2021 is [awesome_nested_set](https://github.com/collectiveidea/awesome_nested_set) which has some documentation about how to "create a text_pattern_ops index for your postgresql column."